# Почему при загрузке фотографии приложение прекращает работу?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Учебный проект на asp.net core MVC.

Код страницы

```
<form asp-controller="Patient" asp-action="RegisterPatient" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Image">Фото</label>
    <input type="file" asp-for="Image" class="form-control" r />
</div>
</form>
```

Код контроллера

```
[Route("RegisterPatient")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterPatient([FromForm] PatientViewModel patientModel)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         PatientEntity patient = patientModel.Patient;

         using MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
         await patientModel.Image.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);

         patient.Image = memoryStream.ToArray(); 

         bool isAdded = await _service.UpdatePatientAsync(TypeOfEntityUpdateCommand.Insert, patient);

         if (isAdded)
             return PartialView("QRCode", QRCode.Generate(patient.Id));
     }

     return View();
 }
```

Большое спасибо

Comment: Приведённом вами коде ошибки нет, ищите её в другом месте. Начните с изучения логов.

Comment: Да, тут только логи какие-то смотреть. Что-то же куда-то выводиться должно.

Comment: Ошибка какая? Где? Когда? Как именно прекращает работу? В какой момент? Из-за каких файлов? Какая ошибка возникает? Может у вас просто контакт отходит и ПК отключается